# How list<T> work dynamically although it internally use array(which is fixed)?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, generics

I already know about generics and array in c#(i know about dynamic array using pointers in c++), also i know that the arrays are fixed size so we can't change its size after Initialization, we have to allocate a new one then copy......

Lately, I've been using ILspy to see source code of .net assemblies and i found that the List internally rely on a private array but i couldn't figure out how it work, so i wondered, how technically it grows or be resized in memory when I mainpulate it?

Comment: See http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `List<T>` allocates an array `T[]` of some size and uses it as storage for its items until the array fills up. When a new item needs to be added after that happens, the list allocates a new, larger array and copies all the items from the old array to the new one. The new item can then be added without problem.

As a result of this behavior, appending items to a `List` is described as an [amortized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amortized_time) O(1) operation: most appends will take constant time since there is free space in the backing array, but *some* appends will trigger an array reallocation and take much more time.

The manner of implementation is also apparent from the public interface of `List`: there is a [`Capacity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y52x03h2.aspx) property that controls how many items the list can hold without resizing and also a [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw8e0z9z.aspx) that lets you reserve some specified capacity up front (useful to avoid needless resize operations when you know from beforehand that the list is going to be at least a certain size).